# why textscan only read one line

Tags: matlab, textscan

I am trying to read a csv file use textscan. The fields are seperated with ',' . I used the following code, but it only read in one line of data into the matrix W.

I also tried dlmread(), it got the number of fields wrong.

The file is contructed under linux, matlab is under linux.

```
file_id = fopen('H:\data\overlapmatrices\cos.mat.10');
W = textscan(file_id, '%f', 'delimiter', ',' , 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
fclose(file_id);
clear file_id;
```

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the answers. I check the results and find that textscan() reads all the fields, but put them all in a cell{1,1} which itself is a {1, 10* numberOfFields}. So textscan() do not recognise lines.

Comment: dlmread() or csvread() which use dlmread() internally, also read all fields  but seperate the line at the wrong place.

Comment: The 1-by-1 cell array is expected as you only specified one pattern to match: `'%f'`. Are there 10 numbers per line? If you want them split into separate cells then you need to specify the pattern to match: `'%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f'` (yes, it's a bit awkward; no, `'EndOfLine'` can't be used instead). I'm not sure if this is really an end-of-line issue, but you can also try not including that parameter.

Comment: Hi horchler, thank you for your reply. But there are still some points that are not clear to me. 1. If 'EndOfLine' is not a delimiter of 'row', then what is the purpose of it? 2. So textscan() will read the whole file, split it into fields use 'delimiter', then use the pattern to mach the fields, one by one. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in how the end of line is represented in the file (see also [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) on Wikipedia). While `\r\n` (the combination of a carriage return and a newline character) is common on Windows, `\n` (just the newline character) is the standard on Linux and other Unix systems.

But as ben is saying, [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) might be an easier way how to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html), it should do the trick.

or you could alway do something dirty like

```
fid = fopen( filename );
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline) %or some other check
    %sscanf(tline...
    tline = fgetl(fid);    
end
```